# Polylang translation issue for one language in WooCommerce cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, translation, multilingual

I am setting up my webshop and have three languages -EN, DE, ES I added polylang and all works fine. EN and ES all correct. For some reason there is a bug in the DE languages though. when going to cart/warenkorb with an added product, it does not translate (Product, Price, Quantity, Subtotal, Coupon Code, Apply coupon and Update cart.) Everything else on the page is translated. I have googeled my brain out and can not find a solution. Any ideas?

German(DE) is set as main polylang language and I am using "Hyyan WooCommerce Polylang Integration" plugin.

These are the links:
DE: `www.washbox-international.com/shop/product/washbox-de`
ES: `www.washbox-international.com/shop/es/product/washbox-es`
EN: `www.washbox-international.com/shop/en/product/washbox`

Thank you and a good weekendy

Comment: Your question doesn't match with StackOverFlow on topic questions. You should better ask in Polylang support pages WooCommerce cart as this seems to be a bug like in an existing software.

Comment: Ah, ok, sorry for that ;) will do!!

Answer (score 0):

Go at woocomerce ->settings -> advanced and check your default page language to be at the cart page and check out page.

I had similar problem . When i pushed the cart button from greek language redirecting me at english cart and not at greek. I solve it by woocomerce ->settings -> advanced